# Sweedish font under IE11

Tags: fonts, internet-explorer-11, font-face

this is very strange. I saw also one similar topic on stack, but no answers there.

Have a look at a part of my screenshot. It's all about special characters in sweedish font under Internet Explorer 11 (only this browser). One paragraph displays correctly, but the other one doesn't...

Can anyone help me where to look for?

## iefix? [image]

Answer (score 0):

I think it is related to the text direction attribute. Maybe for some reason, the letters are displayed from right to left (`rtl`), not from left to right (`ltr`).

If so, you can add attribute `dir` to some tag, which wraps the text:

```
<body dir="ltr">
```

or wrap the text with bug by `bdo` tag:

```
<bdo dir="ltr">The text with bug</bdo>
```

It may also be useful to use the [`unicode-bidi`](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/u/unicode-bidi/) CSS property.

So the solution maybe can be also adding a CSS rule:

```
.selector_to_bug {
    direction: ltr;
    unicode-bidi: embed;
}
```

eventually with or without `!important` declarations.

https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/d/direction/